# Space saga, at least 3 books, female captain,

Tags: story-identification

Late 1980s/early 1990 Space Saga.  Female Captain. Female first mate/security who had been kicked out of the Emperors' Immortals military force (including her lover).  They start at a space station, I believe they take on a stray young runaway child before leaving the space station.

There is a rebellion against the emperor, and it's led by a very charismatic leader(there may be an aspect that no one really knows what he looks like).  The strategy so far by this rebellion is moving around the outer ring planets of empire in an inward spiral.

The protagonists eventually run into the rebels. (I can't remember if they are caught, or this is the only way to make some type of deal etc).  The twist here is when they meet the rebel leader, he's the guy the First Mate had an affair with and got kicked out of the Immortals!  She didn't know he'd led the rebellion.

The book sizes were normal for the time, about the thickness of a Harry Harrison scifi novel. Well written, good action/writing/some good real life humor from the characters during the adventures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[*Highroad Trilogy*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42099-highroad) by Alis A. Rasmussen.  The main character, Lily, meets up with the captain and the first mate who is her lover.  Both of them belonged to the Immortals of the emperor, who were supposed to be celibate; both got pregnant by the same man, and had to flee. The captain miscarried, but they have the first mate's child.

There is a rebellion, and somewhat later, they do meet the leader, and he is the lover responsible.

Comment: awesome, that's the one. thank you very much! Now to track them down lol.  The other thing is I remember a tip way back:  if you like a book/author, keep a running list of the great ones.

Comment: and I'm struggling in finding how to label my question as Answered.  apologies on that.

Comment: @zbd you hit the checkmark on the left.

Comment: @Zbd you don't mark you question itself as answered. You mark an answer as "accepted", with the check mark on the left of the answer.

Comment: thanks! of course right in front of me lol.

Comment: As you've likely already found. Alis A. Rasmussen now writes as Kate Elliott. Her Jaran series takes place in the same universe as the Highroad Trilogy but earlier.